# Microsoft Access finding second, third, Nth element in a group

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a table: `worker_id`, `company_id`

`worker_id` is primary key

```
worker_id | company_id
----------------------
 1        | 1
 2        | 1
 3        | 2
 4        | 3
 5        | 3
 6        | 1
```

I know how to find the first `worker_id` in each `company_id` using `Min()`

```
SELECT Min([workers per company].worker_id) AS MinOfworker_id, [workers per company].company_id
FROM [workers per company]
GROUP BY [workers per company].company_id;
```

Resulting in:

```
worker_id | company_id
----------------------
 1        | 1
 3        | 2
 4        | 3
```

I know how to find the last `worker_id` in each `company_id` using `Max()`

```
SELECT Max([workers per company].worker_id) AS MaxOfworker_id, [workers per company].company_id
FROM [workers per company]
GROUP BY [workers per company].company_id;
```

Resulting in:

```
worker_id | company_id
----------------------
 6        | 1
 3        | 2
 5        | 3
```

Now I want to get the second (or third, Nth) `worker_id` per `company_id` resulting in:

```
worker_id | company_id
----------------------
 2        | 1
 5        | 3
```

There is a way to do this?

EDIT:

In kdb+ I can use:

> select w:worker_id[1] by company_id from workers_per_company

to get the 2nd worker_id

resulting in:

```
company_id| w
-------------
 1        | 2
 2        | 
 3        | 5
```

Is there something similar in MS Access?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do something in SQL that SQL was not meant for. Instead, consider writing a VBA procedure to iterate over a recordset sorted by company.